# Howto parse runlength encoded binary subformat with antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Given the following input:

```
AA:4:2:@5@xxAAx:2:a:
```

The part @5@ defines the start of a binary subformat with the length of 5. The sub format can contain any kind of character and is likely to contain tokens from the main format. (ex. AA is a keyword/token inside the main format).

I want to build a lexer that is able to extract one token for the whole binary part.

I already tried several approaches (ex. partials, sematic predicates) but I did not get them working together the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution by myself.

Below are the relevant parts of the lexer definition

```
@members {
    public int _binLength;
}

BINARYHEAD: '@' [0-9]+ '@'  { _binLength = Integer.parseInt(getText().substring(1,getText().length()-1)); } -> pushMode(RAW) ;

mode RAW;

BINARY: .+ {getText().length() <= _binLength}? -> popMode;
```

The solution is based on an extra field that set while parsing the length definition of the binary field. Afterward a semantic predicate is used to restrict the validity of the binary content to the size of that field.

Any suggestion to simplify the `parseInt` call is welcome.